How is it possible that this JSON file can have comments?
I'm taking an online course and the presenter opens a JSON file in VSCode which has comments in it.
No errors are showing and he doesn't mention or speak to this as if having comments in a JSON file is completely normal.
How is this possible?


Does this answer your question? Can comments be used in JSON?

You have a file tsconfig.json there. Open it, add a comment and you see it does not highlight it as an error. That's because VSCode special-cases files named like this. Rename it and there will be an error.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-with-comments - you can see in the file view icons it's not just being treated as "a JSON file".

This isn't strictly valid JSON, but it may be pre-processed or an interpreter which understands this extra syntax may still be able to parse it
